# How to pass value from AJAX to codebehind in mvc? string values are null came

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

```
$(document).ready(function () {      
    $("#btn").click(function () {         
        var data = {
            "Username": $("#name").val(),
            "Password":$("#pswd").val()
        }  
        $.ajax({
            url: "/loginform/logdetail",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            type: "post",
            ContentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",            
            datatype: "json", 
            success: function (response) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var result = JSON.parse(response.d);
                if (result.status == "success") {
                    window.location = "https://www.google.co.in";
                    return false;
                }    
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("errormessage");
            }
        })   
    });
});
```

In the `logdetail()` method, the string value is `null`. How do I get string value?

```
public JsonResult logdetail(string Username, string Password)
{
    return Json(dbform.checkuser(Username,Password),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                           
}
```

Comment: Remove `ContentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",` (its actually `contentType` - lower case - but its not needed) and use `data: data,` (not stringified)

Comment: Add HttpPost attribute to logdetail action and you dont neet JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet

OR

change javascript call method type with "get"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few mistakes in your code :

Especially these 2 lines

`contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` `data: JSON.stringify({ userdataObj: data })`

Your ajax code will become :

```
$(document).ready(function () {      
    $("#btn").click(function () {         
        var data = {
            "Username": $("#name").val(),
            "Password":$("#pswd").val()
        }  
        $.ajax({
            url: "/loginform/logdetail",
            data: JSON.stringify({ userdataObj: data }),
            type: "post",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",          
            datatype: "json", 
            success: function (response) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var result = JSON.parse(response.d);
                if (result.status == "success") {
                    window.location = "https://www.google.co.in";
                    return false;
                }    
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("errormessage");
            }
        })   
    });
});
```

Now create a User data class with below details

```
public class User 
{ 
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password{ get; set; }
}
```

And change controller to below code :

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult logdetail(User userdataObj)
{
    return Json(dbform.checkuser(userdataObj.Username,userdataObj.Password),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                           
}
```

Comment: iam giving username and paswd in textbox but in codebehind came null value

Comment: Put the `[HttpPost]` attribute above your controller action method.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look following solution, First better to put preventDefault(); outside of success function, And create Class in server side same as JSON object

```
public class User { 
 public string Username { get; seet; }
 public string Password{ get; seet; }
}
```

change action to

```
public JsonResult logdetail(User user) {..}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with OP's problem and the values will still be `null`

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things to solve this issue.

1) Create `User` class with two properties (Username, Password), modify your `logdetail` function like this `logdetail(User user)` and use your version of javascript ajax call.

2) If you want to use same version of controller (`logdetail(string Username, string Password)`), then you have to modify your javascript ajax call.

```
$(document).ready(function () {      
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        var username = $("#name").val();
        var password = $("#pswd").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/loginform/logdetail",
            data: { Username: username, Password: password } 
            type: "post",
            ContentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",            
            datatype: "json", 
            success: function (response) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var result = JSON.parse(response.d);
                if (result.status == "success") {
                    window.location = "https://www.google.co.in";
                    return false;
                }    
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("errormessage");
            }
        })   
    });
});
```